# How should I correctly assign cout to a static ostream reference variable?

Tags: c++, iostream, ostream

I'm defining a class like this:

```
class StaticRuntimeContext {
 public:
  enum Verbosity {
    kHIGH,
    kMEDIUM,
    kLOW,
    kSILENT
  };
  static void Construct();
  static std::ostream& stdout1() {return stdout1_;}
  static std::ostream& stdout2() {return stdout2_;}
  static std::ostream& stdout3() {return stdout3_;}
  static std::ostream& stderr() {return stderr_;}
 protected:
 private:
  static std::ostream& stdout1_;
  static std::ostream& stdout2_;
  static std::ostream& stdout3_;
  static std::ostream& stderr_;
};
```

I'm defining the construct function as:

```
void StaticRuntimeContext::Construct() {
  std::ostream& test = cout;
  stdout1_ = cout;
  stdout2_ = cout;
  //stdout3_ = NULL;
  stderr_ = cerr;
}
```

I cannot understand why assigning cout to test (std::ostream&) is OK to compile but the compiler produces error messages for the rest like "stdout1_=cout". The error message is:

```
/usr/lib/gcc/x86_64-redhat-linux/4.6.2/../../../../include/c++/4.6.2/bits/ios_base.h:791:5: error: ‘std::ios_base& std::ios_base::operator=(const std::ios_base&)’ is private
```

I'm wondering what I should do to correctly assign cout to these ostream reference variables. Thanks!

Comment: One sidenote: One thing that befuddles me is why "std::ostream& test = cout;" can compile but "stdout_1 = cout" cannot...

Comment: You can't rebind a reference after its construction, so that's an attempt to copy between the actual streams... which you also can't do.

Answer (score 10, accepted):

It's because references have value semantics, and the operator = is copying the object instead of assigning a new reference.

Instead of references you should define static pointers, assign them in Construct, and return references in your accessors

```
  static std::ostream& stdout1() {return *stdout1_;}
  static std::ostream& stdout2() {return *stdout2_;}
  static std::ostream& stdout3() {return *stdout3_;}
  static std::ostream& stderr()  {return *stderr_;}
 protected:
 private:
  static std::ostream* stdout1_;
  static std::ostream* stdout2_;
  static std::ostream* stdout3_;
  static std::ostream* stderr_;

void StaticRuntimeContext::Construct() {
  stdout1_ = &cout;
  stdout2_ = &cout;
  stdout3_ = &cout;
  stderr_ = &cerr;
}
```

EDIT:
And you must add this in your .cpp file

```
std::ostream* StaticRuntimeContext::stdout1_ = NULL;
std::ostream* StaticRuntimeContext::stdout2_ = NULL;
std::ostream* StaticRuntimeContext::stdout3_ = NULL;
std::ostream* StaticRuntimeContext::stderr_ = NULL;
```

Comment: Still the same question...then why "std::ostream& test = cout;" can pass the compilation then?

Comment: Because that creates a reference to `std::cout`, the rest are already created references, so it uses copy-assignment instead

Comment: @derekhh: `std::ostream& test = cout;` initialises the reference, and has nothing to do with your other uses of `=` (which mean completely different things).

Comment: One quick question: After changing the class declaration from references to pointers, compiling seems OK this time, but in linker it  produces error messages in forms like: "static_runtime_context.cc:(.text+0x7): undefined reference to `StaticRuntimeContext::stdout1_'"...

Comment: see the Edit for your last comment

Comment: @GabrielCuvillier Er, I'm not so sure that is the case since I've actually defined another static private variable "static boost::timer stopwatch_" in the class. And I've tried to initialize this timer by calling "stopwatch_.restart()" in the StaticRuntimeContext::Construct() function. However, it also provides an error message saying that "static_runtime_context.cc:(.text+0x2d): undefined reference to `StaticRuntimeContext::stopwatch_'"

Comment: @GabrielCuvillier: And by the way, if I move the implementation of Construct function from the .cc file to the header file, seems everything is OK..strange to me...

Comment: Got it! :) Static objects must also be declared outside any function or class just like normal globals.

Answer (score 2):

This code

```
std::ostream& test = cout;
```

is not an assignment, but a construction of a new reference. It can also be written

```
std::ostream& test(cout);
```

without the equal sign. The effect is the same.

A reference cannot be rebound once it is created, so it must be set to its value when created. The static members also have to be defined somewhere, like in the corresponding .cpp file. Just set the values there:

```
 std::ostream& StaticRuntimeContext::stdout1_ = std::cout;
 std::ostream& StaticRuntimeContext::stdout2_ = std::cout;
 std::ostream& StaticRuntimeContext::stdout3_ = std::clog;
 std::ostream& StaticRuntimeContext::stderr_  = std::cerr;
```

Answer (score 0):

In C++ reference variables must be initialized when they are declared.

valid:

```
int x;
int& foo = x;
```

Invalid:

```
int x;
int& foo;
foo = x;
```

Comment: Almost but not quite. `foo = x` is perfectly valid; it just means something else.

Answer (score 0):

You need to use a pointer, because references do not allow rebind and `std::ostream` is noncopyable.

Answer (score 0):

> I cannot understand why assigning cout to test (std::ostream&) is OK to compile

Because that **isn't assignment**; it's initialization.